# jQuery getting the item that called the function and removing it's parent

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that removes the item, code looks like this

```
<li><a onclick="remove('9', 1);">Remove</a></li>
```

With jquery, how would I remove the whole 'li' when remove is clicked?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the onClick event I'd prefer to use the following way:

```
<li><a id="remove">Remove</a></li>

$('#remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Can't do as I have to pass data through

Comment: The `$(this)` selector and the traversing to `.parent()` should still be applicable inside your function, since your `<a>` is the sender. You cannot, however, use the `.click()` though if i remember correctly, since it will stop onClick from triggering.

Comment: You can still pass data in a number of ways.  1 would be to use `data-foo` type attributes, e.g. `<a id="remove" data-foo="9">Remove</a>` then just access `$(this).attr('data-foo')` in the function.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to following:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

The `"a"` selector likely needs to be changed to match the exact `<a>` elements you want.